# Sqlite and counting the frequency of multiple fields

Tags: sqlite, count

I have a table named "number" with 4 columns (id, N1,N2,N3) like this:

```
id = 1,2 3, 4


N1 = 22 , 14 , 13 , 15

N2 = 13 , 11 , 80 , 11

N3 = 11 , 22 , 47 , 23
```

Can I count the total frequency of individual numbers in this table?
`(11 = 3) ** (22=2)` etc..

For one column my query is:

```
"SELECT N1, COUNT(*) as Frequency FROM number GROUP BY n1 order by count(*) desc"
```

Thanks for the possible help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT t.num, COUNT(t.num)
FROM (SELECT N1 AS num FROM number
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N2 AS num FROM number
      UNION ALL
      SELECT N3 AS num FROM number) AS t
GROUP BY t.num
ORDER BY COUNT(t.num) desc;
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9b57f/8)

[UNION operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm)